# error: 502 bad gateway in flask app on nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, nginx, flask

I am deploying a flask app on Ubuntu server using Nginix, uWSGI. I followed this tutorial... http://www.soundrenalin.com/about

I am beginner in Nignix and Sys Admin.

But when i run my app it gives error: `502 Bad Gateway`

I looked into log file and it says:

```
Starting uWSGI 1.2.3-debian (32bit) on [Sun May 19 05:39:19 2013] 
***compiled with version: 4.7.1 on 17 September 2012 17:20:40 detected number of CPU cores: 1 current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core your memory page size is 4096 bytes detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexesunlink(): Operation not permitted [socket.c line 75]
bind(): Address already in use [socket.c line 107] removed uwsgi instance flaskapp.ini
```

Why this is happening? Please Suggest

Answer (score -2, accepted):

take a look at the new docs in the same URL (https://github.com/kholidfu/serverthings/blob/master/serversetup.org). It's in indonesian, but there is a code snippet everywhere, hope you can understand it

Comment: Dead link as of 5/30/14.